# How to modify a text file using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, filewriter, printwriter

http://pastebin.com/E5TspHfK - Object Class, named PhoneBookEntry
http://pastebin.com/Ce94SJzB - Method Class, named PhoneBook
http://pastebin.com/ENsVT0jJ - Tester Class, named PhoneBookTester

Basically my aim with these three classes is to make a "Phone Book" -- a text-based program that allows people to create a database of their contacts that they can add entries to, edit/delete/display the entries of, search, and sort the entries.

The PhoneBookEntry object array that the program is creating is output to a text file, which displays them in the format "fName\tlName\tnumber". These are obviously the various variables that can be stored in the PhoneBookEntry class.

The question is, to write to the text file I have to use the PrintWriter class, but how do I make it so that the text file is updated if the order of the array is rearranged? Because I don't send added entries to the array, I send them to the text file itself, but if you use the sort or edit function, you modify the content of the array, not the text file.

So how do I make it possible to modify the contents of the text file itself if you can't 'write backwards' with the PrintWriter class? Relevant bits of code are pasted below.

**PhoneBook:**

```
public static int filledTil=-1;    
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Hana\\Desktop\\PhoneBook.txt");
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(fw);
static PhoneBookEntry[] phoneBook = new PhoneBookEntry[500];

    public PhoneBook() throws IOException {            
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Hana\\Desktop\\PhoneBook.txt"));
        while(input.hasNext()){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
            String fName = sc.next();
            String lName = sc.next();
            String number = sc.next();
            filledTil++;
            phoneBook[filledTil] = new PhoneBookEntry(fName, lName, number);
        }
        input.close();
    }
```

**PhoneBook Sort Methods**

```
public static int partition(){
            int lo = 0;
            int hi = filledTil;
            PhoneBookEntry temp;
            PhoneBookEntry pivot = phoneBook[(lo + hi) / 2];
            while(lo <= hi){
                while(phoneBook[lo].lName.compareTo(pivot.lName) < 0){
                    lo++;
                }
                while(phoneBook[lo].lName.compareTo(pivot.lName) > 0){
                    hi--;
                }
                if(lo <= hi) {
                    temp = phoneBook[lo];
                    phoneBook[lo] = phoneBook[hi];
                    phoneBook[hi] = temp;
                    lo++;
                    hi--;
                }
            };
            return lo;
        }

        public static void quickSort(int lo, int hi){
            int index = partition();
            if(lo < (index - 1)){
                quickSort(lo, (index-1));
            }
            if(index < hi){
                quickSort(index, hi);
            }
        }
```

**PhoneBook Quit Method**

```
public void quit(){
        output.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you "have" to use `PrintWriter`? What's wrong with a `BufferedWriter`? Also as short answer: if you sort all your data, just resave the entire file (i.e. overwrite it with the updated, sorted data)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans What's the difference?

Comment: @Hanalei a buffered writer is more efficient as it writes in batches.  That's only difference.  Mike is correct though.  Just overwrite the entire file with whatever modifications the user made.  Tracking and writing only the changes is more work and unnecessary for the quantity of data you're working with.